# Disable email account on iOS without knowing the account password?

Tags: ios, ipad, mail.app

We have an iPad/iOS11.x that has a link to a Yahoo account. The account is no longer used and the password expired. We'd like to simply turn off the account, so it stops checking for email but doesn't delete everything

However, when we go the account settings, everything is greyed out. For instance, the button that lets you turn email on or off is set to on, and we can't change it.

I suspect this is because we don't have the password for the account? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Note on IMA the data is really still on the server and only synced to your local device. If you want to keep the data you should copy the mails off the server.

Comment: iOS mail doesn’t store locally? I thought it only left attachments on the server and downloaded the text?

Comment: It copies the text but if the server is still available and if another client deletes the text on the server it will be deleted from the iPhone. I am assuming it uses IMAP - POP would do as you expect but I don't think IPhones do that by default if at all.

Comment: Oh I see. So then (having never done this), does deleting the account make all the mail go away locally? Or does it remain accessible?

Comment: It will go away if the Mail is synced or attempted to sync. Don't rely on it staying in mailboxes that match imap folders

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few things and I think you are mistaken about the lost password being the problem. Check settings->Mail and make sure that the account in question is not your Default account. If so, make another account the Default. Then go back to Settings->Accounts and the Mail slider in the broken account should be active and you can turn it off. But that will still remove all the old messages.

If there are important messages that you want to keep, the only way I know on iOS is to print them to PDFs and keep them in notes. Heres and article on how to do that: [How to Save email on iOS as notes](https://9to5mac.com/2017/03/28/how-to-save-email-notes-ios/)

Comment: Ok I'll have a go. It's not my iPad, so it will be this weekend before I see it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may just need to scroll down to see the delete account button.

Comment: That deletes the account and all the mail. We want to keep the mail.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you don't want to delete the account. I tried a few things and added a new answer.